# What function would I used to remove duplicate numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list, methods, duplicates

I have 2 different lists that I combine into one list (list3). How would I remove the duplicates in the list?

note: can't use set() method

Comment: why can't you use set?

Comment: list(dict.fromkeys(list3))

Comment: any other methods? it was used in a different code and the assignment asks to find new methods. dict. function has been used too

Comment: np.unique(list3)

Comment: maybe you can list the function you already came up with, so we don't add those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = []
for i in list3:
   if i not in s:
      s.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.unique(list3).tolist()
```

Comment: OP doesn't say anything about pandas and there is no need to introduce such a huge dependency. This can be solved using the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
np.unique(list3).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to the rescue.

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 2]

data = [g[0] for g in groupby(sorted(data))]
print(data)
```

This will give you `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 16]`.

Answer (score 0):

Evil stuff for a list with non-negative integers. Bonus: the resulting list is sorted.

```
data = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 2]
pool = [False] * (max(data) + 1)
for value in data:
    pool[value] = True
data = [i for i, j in enumerate(pool) if j]
print(data)
```